# HTML Form Input to External Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, solr

*Most of the solutions I have found deal with localized javascript instead of an external file so I am posting this question.
Links to attempted solutions:*

[Turn HTML Form Input into JavaScript Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982774/turn-html-form-input-into-javascript-variable)

I want to take a html form input and use that input in an external javascript file.

The html form input comes from `index.html`

```
<script src="script/our.js"></script>
<div class="searchbar">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search ..." name="query" onchange=formChange()>
        <button type="submit">sendit bro</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function formChange(){
        var searchThis = document.getElementsByName("query").value;
    }
</script>
```

Then, our.js tries to use the variable like so:

```
var Manager;
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        Manager.store.addByValue('q', searchThis);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

With my current setup, if I searched a term ("unlock") the form will send and the page will show it has found 0 documents. It does **not** say that `searchThis` is undefined
The back end of my js works with `searchThis` being replaced by `"*:*"` to display all records instead of those with the searched string.

**EDIT #1** : `Manager.jquery.js` to see if I need to allow for search term to be a variable an not just a string
**REDACTED**

**EDIT #2** : 
I have been trying suggestions below. Currently:

`index.html`changed

```
<script>
    function formChange(){
        var searchThis = document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value;
        console.log(searchThis);
        window.searchThis = searchThis;
        console.log(window.searchThis);
    }
</script>
```

`our.js`changed

```
    Manager.store.addByValue('q', window.searchThis);
```

The `console.log`s in `index.html` return my search term. However if I do the same just before `window.searchThis` is called in `our.js` it returns as undefined.

**EDIT #3** 
I have been playing with importing the `searchThis` variable. I cannot `import window.searchThis` because I get an error for unexpected `.` In full when I try:

```
import searchThis from "../index.html"
```

It gives me an error stating:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

**EDIT #4** : my `<form>` + `<script>` section with adjustments

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search Nicola..." name="query" onsubmit=formChange() >
        <button type="submit">sendit bro</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function formChange(){
        searchThis = document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value;
        term = searchThis;
        console.log(term);
    }
</script>
<script defer="defer" src="script/our.js" type="module"></script>
```

Ive added my form section because I could be doing something wrong here too. When I go to my main page the `console.log` on `our.js` has already been logged as undefined. When I enter a search term with `onchange` instead of `onsubmit` the console logs from my `<script>`. Once I hit submit, the page flashes and the log for `our.js` is again at the top and undefined.

**EDIT #5** : pic of logs described above (before submit)
[image]

Comment: `searchThis` is local to `formChange`.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry, not sure how to change that to make `searchThis` global. I changed my `our.js` from `searchThis` to `formChange.searchThis` but that hasn't helped my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window` object.

Add a new property named `searchThis` to the `window` object and assign the obtained value of the `searchThis` variable.

```
function formChange() {
  var searchThis = document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value;
  window.searchThis = searchThis;
}
```

Then, just call it by using `window.searchThis`:

```
var Manager;
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    Manager.store.addByValue('q', window.searchThis);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Update:** `document.getElementsByName("query")` returns a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You could use **`document.getElementsByName("query")[0]`** to refer to a single element.

The availability of a variable for reuse in another external file depends on the order of loading or initialization.

The issue that you have is that `our.js` is running before the `window.searchThis` is declared.

You can do:

1. Add a `defer` attribute in the `script` tag. Example: `<script defer="defer" src="script/our.js"></script>`.

OR

2. Put the `<script src="script/our.js"></script>` at the end.

Something like this:

```
<script>
  function formChange() {
    var searchThis = document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value;
    window.searchThis = searchThis;
  }
</script>
<script src="script/our.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. If the `window.searchThis` in `our.js` is replaced with a string like "unlock" it will display all documents related to that term. If that function is expecting a string instead of a variable, would that cause issues? I haven't gotten an error when using a variable in place of the search term.

Comment: Ive added `console.log(document.getElementsByName("query").value)` right after `var searchThis...` The console says it is undefined.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("query")` returns a `NodeList`. You should use `console.log(document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, so this did allow `window.searchThis` in `our.js` to be my search term. Now when I access the same `window.searchThis` in `Manager.jquery.js` it is shown as undefined.

Comment: `window.searchThis` is declared like any type. It can be a `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `object`, `array`. It depends its contents.

Comment: The availability of a variable for reuse in another external file depends on the order of loading or initialization. You could add a `defer="defer"` attribute in the: `<script defer="defer" src="script/our.js"></script>`.

Comment: An edit to my 3rd comment here: `our.js` **->** `index.html` & `Manager.jquery.js` **->** `our.js`

Comment: unfortunately Im still not able to get access to `window.searchThis` in `our.js`. This is after ive made your suggested changes. The `console.log(window.searchThis)` in `index.html` is correct but when logged just before `Manager.store.addByValue` it shows as undefined. I have tried the defer method and moving the `<script src=...>`

Comment: I have been playing with `defer` as well as moving the `<script src..>` more because when I load my main page the `console.log` for `our.js` has already output to the console. When I load a search term into the box, the logs from the html page appear. Once I click the submit button the page flashes and the undefined `our.js` log is alone at the top of the console. Im going to link my `form` section as an edit.

Comment: The page flashes because you are submitting the form with default form submission action, so your will never run that you want to do. Can you add an `id` attribute in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: I can, I just added `id="searchform"` to the `<form>` tag

Comment: I see... You must run `Manager.store.addByValue('q', searchThis);` only when you submit the form. What is Manager.jquery.js?

Comment: Other observation is in our.js file. `Manager.store.addByValue('q', window.searchThis);` The `Manager` object always is `undefined`, so you can't call `Manager.store.addByValue`.

Comment: for some context Im trying to follow sections of the reuters ajax solr tutorial  https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial       in this they are able to use that manager but leave "*:*" as the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191123/discussion-between-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez-and-newb-4-you-bb).

Comment: @Newb4YouBB I've made a simple demo in Plunker recreating your scenario in this link: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OcHSHFuJrtdLl6ft?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to use your demo yet, but I wanted to thank you ahead of time. Always appreciate those who are willing to assist beyond expectation. Thank you.